# Xvfb and Selenium temp files are not automatically deleted from /tmp (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, xvfb, buildbot

We have Buildbot on remote server to run python selenium tests.
After a couple of days the tmp rubbish from XVFB and Selenium totaly consume all empty space and freeze the Buildbot activity. I used to clear /tmp it manualy with `sudo rm -rf *` in /tmp folder and then  `sudo supervisorctl restart all`

I write simple preparing step what do it automatically before all steps. But it provide some xvfb errors like some tmp file not found.
Without proper restart it wont work well. And i dont know how to properly restart builbot(or XVFB?) without some *deadly loop of self-restarting and building again*

Comment: At least provide error message on cleanup step. Also are you sure you using `xvfb` and not `xvfb-run`? If so, do you try to add  `-f` to store extra data in specific dir and not temp?

Comment: yes its actually `xvfb-run`, but i dont think what i will freely delete xvfb files even in different folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find source of /tmp bloating
2. Make sure only /tmp is bloating
3. Try to use http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/tmpreaper.8.html